# Top corners of UINavigationBar are being rounded off in iOS6

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios6

I have a UINavigation bar with a custom background that I set like this in the viewDidLoad method of my code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"V2_navbar"];
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

In iOS 5 the result looked like this:

[image]

In iOS 6 the result looks like this:

[image]

For one thing the status bar is now black, which is ok. But if you look closely at the second image you will notice that the top corners of my navigation bar are now rounded off, which looks bad.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: ...in my opinion it does not look bad for the black status bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on quick experiments...

As a workaround, just set your status bar style to black translucent in your project settings. That has the net effect that your `UIWindow` is given the whole screen including the area behind the status bar — on a 3.5" device your window will be 480pts rather than 460. However unless your view controller sets `wantsFullScreenLayout` to `YES` you won't be expected to paint that area and it'll look identical to black opaque.

If your code is then setting the status bar style programmatically somewhere, you probably want to disable that.

EDIT: to answer Matt.Z's concerns... Apple has added rounded corners because the designers there sometimes like rounded corners at the screen edges. The original 1984 Macintosh desktop had them on all four corners and they survived through to OS 9, OS X originally retained them in the two top corners but then they vanished in 10.5.

In this case they seem to have gone the other way, deciding to add rounded corners to 'the edge of the display' between iOS 5 and 6. So they've been added purely for aesthetic reasons, by Apple.

By setting `wantsFullScreenLayout` to `YES` you extend the area that your application is able to use as the full screen right the way up underneath the status bar so 'the edge of the display' stops being the top of your navigation bar. Since Apple doesn't want to break apps by cutting chunks out of the middle of their display area, iOS hence doesn't add the corners.

Comment: I think this answer did not tell why in iOS6 the corners are round, and how to get rid of it .